# jQuery Filter divs By Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to filter `div`s by their class, but I'm having some trouble. For some reason, if any button is pressed, everything disappears. I've been troubleshooting this for a while now and I can't figure out why this is happening. A CodePen is [here](http://codepen.io/terf/pen/vGeqC) and my attempt is below:

HTML:

```
<button class="active btn" id="all">Show All</button>
<button class="btn" id="a">Show A</button>
<button class="btn" id="b">Show B</button>
<button class="btn" id="c">Show C</button>
<button class="btn" id="d">Show D</button>
<br />
<div class="a b">a &amp; b</div>
<div class="a">a</div>
<div class="b">b</div>
<div class="c">c</div>
<div class="d">d</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  background: #eee;
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $("#all").click(function() {
    $("div").fadeIn(500);
    $("#all").addClass("active");
    $(":not(#all)").removeClass("active");
  });
  $("#a").click(function() {
    $(".a").fadeIn(500);
    $(":not(.a)").fadeOut(0);
    $("#a").addClass("active");
    $(":not(#a)").removeClass("active");
  });
  $("#b").click(function() {
    $(".b").fadeIn(500);
    $(":not(.b)").fadeOut(0);
    $("#b").addClass("active");
    $(":not(#b)").removeClass("active");
  });
  $("#c").click(function() {
    $(".c").fadeIn(500);
    $(":not(.c)").fadeOut(0);
    $("#c").addClass("active");
    $(":not(#c)").removeClass("active");
  });
  $("#d").click(function() {
    $(".d").fadeIn(500);
    $(":not(.d)").fadeOut(0);
    $("#d").addClass("active");
    $(":not(#d)").removeClass("active");
  });

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because of the selector `$(":not(.b)")` which selects all elements and hides it except `.b` which will include the `body` element also.

You need to use a more specific selector, one option is to use a container element like

```js
var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {
  if (this.id == 'all') {
    $('#ct > div').show();
  } else {
    var $el = $('.' + this.id).show();
    $('#ct > div').not($el).hide();
  }
  $btns.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="active btn" id="all">Show All</button>
<button class="btn" id="a">Show A</button>
<button class="btn" id="b">Show B</button>
<button class="btn" id="c">Show C</button>
<button class="btn" id="d">Show D</button>
<br />
<div id="ct">
  <div class="a b">a &amp; b</div>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
  <div class="d">d</div>
</div>
```

---

Using a common selector like an element selector `div` also may not work as it could target other non related elements, so another option is to use a common class to all elements that need to be targeted.

```js
var $items = $('.item');
var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {
  if (this.id == 'all') {
    $items.show();
  } else {
    var $el = $('.' + this.id).show();
    $items.not($el).hide();
  }
  $btns.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="active btn" id="all">Show All</button>
<button class="btn" id="a">Show A</button>
<button class="btn" id="b">Show B</button>
<button class="btn" id="c">Show C</button>
<button class="btn" id="d">Show D</button>
<br />
<div class="item a b">a &amp; b</div>
<div class="item a">a</div>
<div class="item b">b</div>
<div class="item c">c</div>
<div class="item d">d</div>
```

Note: Also as you can see, there is no need to write separate click handlers for each button - given that the `id` of the button and the class you are looking for is the same.

Comment: Wait, but the snippet adds the `active` class to the text, not the button.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this selector, for example:

```
:not(.d)
```

...will select everything that doesn't have class `.d`, including the body and all the buttons, etc. Restricting it more, like:

```
div:not(.d)
```

...should work. See my fix: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cyhIK

Answer (score 0):

sorting table content based on **class name**
May be it will help some one:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$("table tbody tr").sort(function (a, b){
    return $("td", b).attr("class") < $("td", a).attr("class") ? 1 : -1;    
}).appendTo('table tbody');
```

**sort table row values based on class name:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>A column</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="x">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="c">B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="">C</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```